# Web Hook to Post data to an Incoming Service Connection Error (404) on Azure Devops On-Premise

Tags: azure, azure-devops

i want to trigger a pipeline when workItem State change to 'Closed'. to handle that i tried following steps as requirement to trigger pipeline:

1. Define an "Incoming Service Connection" to make web hook url post available for pipeline.
2. Define a Web hook (set the desired event setting) and set URL to this: `https://{org}/defaultcollection/{project}/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/UpdateWorkItemState?api-version=7.0` which UpdateWorkItemState is webhook name in service connection defined in previous step.

but when testing Web Hook i encountered **404 not found** error.

**Incoming Service Connection Definition:**

[image]

**Web Hook Definition:**

[image]

**Test Window:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the `404` issue with the URL that you shared. You seemed to have been using a wrong URL. According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops-2022&tabs=example), there is no `Project` in the URL, which also saves us the trouble adding the authentication token.

[image]

To avoid any other misconfiguration to trigger the pipeline by WebHook, I have shared my sample as below. Hope the information could help.

1. For Azure DevOps Server, the URL I use is as below without `Project` in the URL;

   ```
   http://<TFSInstance>/<CollectionName>/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/<WebHookName>?api-version=6.0-preview
   ```

   For Azure DevOps Service, the URL should be;

   ```
   https://dev.azure.com/<OrgName>/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/<WebHookName>?api-version=6.0-preview
   ```
2. The value of 'WebHookName' from the above URL should be used in the `Incoming WebHook` service connection;

   [image]
3. Add `webhook` resource in the YAML pipeline referencing the Incoming WebHook service connection, which will listen the requests;

   ```
   resources:
     webhooks:
     - webhook: WebHook1
       connection: WebHookSvcCnnClosedWIT #Incoming WebHook service 
   connection name
   steps:
   - task: PowerShell@2
     inputs:
       targetType: 'inline'
          script: 'Write-Host "WIT ID is ${{ parameters.WebHook1.resource.id }}"' #Use the value sent from the WebHook request payload
   ```
4. Kindly also note that only the `webhook` resource defined in the YAML file from the pipeline **default** branch will listen the requests; that is to say, if the `webhook` resource is defined in the YAML file from **non-default** branch, the pipeline will not be triggered and we will get a failed webhook request history.
   [image]

Comment: thank you for you descriptive response and advices.